# Call server side method at client side using signalR

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am working on an auction site which is in 3-Tier architecture.There is one server side method in AuctionHub.cs file as follows:

```
public BAL.LiveAuctionBAL AuctionBid(string Lot_Id, string InputAmt,    string vendorid, string V_AuctionID, string AddModBy, string OpenBidAmt,  string Decrementbid, string LastBidAmount, string auctionEndTimer)
{
   BAL.LiveAuctionBAL BAL = new BAL.LiveAuctionBAL();
   string result = "";
   string msg = "", message = "";
   try
   {
     BAL.Auction_Id = Convert.ToInt32(V_AuctionID);
     BAL.Lot_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Lot_Id);
     BAL.Vendor_Id = Convert.ToInt32(vendorid);
     BAL.Bid_Amount = Convert.ToDouble(InputAmt);
     if (auctionEndTimer != "")
     {
        BAL.AuctionEndTimer = DateTime.Parse(auctionEndTimer.ToString());
     }
     else
     {
        BAL.AuctionEndTimer = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1900");
     }

        BAL.AddMod_By = AddModBy;

        result = BAL.AddAuctionBid();

        if (result != "")
        {
             msg = result;
             this.Clients.All.bidUpdated(result);
        }
     }
    catch
     {

     }
      return BAL;
     }
   }
```

Now I am trying to call this method at client side as follows:

```
     var chat = $.connection.auctionhub;
       $(function () {
       $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.auctionbid(Lot_Id, InputAmt, vendorid, V_AuctionID, AddModBy, OpenBidAmt, Decrementbid, LastBidAmount, auctionEndTimer);
      });
     });
```

but the method is not getting called at  client side.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the references to SignalR or jQuery libraries are incorrect. Try by using something like [ResolveClientUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl(v=vs.110).aspx) or absolute paths for those files. You should check the browser console for any errors.